# What are the tradeoffs between jax.lax.map and jax.vmap?

Tags: python, jax

This [Github issue](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/2940) hints that there are tradeoffs in performance / memory / compilation time when choosing between `jax.lax.map` and `jax.vmap`. What are the specific details of these tradeoffs with respect to both GPUs and CPUs?

Comment: Have you tried running benchmarks between the two solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main difference is that `jax.vmap` is a vectorizing transformation, while `lax.map` is an iterative transformation. Let's look at an example.

#### Example function: `vector_dot`

Suppose you have implemented a simple function that takes 1D vectors as inputs. For simplicity let's make it a simple dot product, but one that asserts the inputs are one-dimensional:

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import numpy as np

def vector_dot(x, y):
  assert x.ndim == y.ndim == 1, "vector inputs required"
  return jnp.dot(x, y)
```

We can create some random 1D vectors to test this:

```py
rng = np.random.default_rng(8675309)
x = rng.uniform(size=50)
y = rng.uniform(size=50)

print(vector_dot(x, y))
# 14.919376
```

To see what JAX is doing with this function under the hood, we can print the [`jaxpr`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jaxpr.html), which is JAX's intermediate-level representation of a function:

```py
print(jax.make_jaxpr(vector_dot)(x, y))
# { lambda ; a:f32[50] b:f32[50]. let
#     c:f32[] = dot_general[dimension_numbers=(([0], [0]), ([], []))] a b
#   in (c,) }
```

This shows that JAX lowers this code to a single call to [`dot_general`](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/operation_semantics#dotgeneral), the primitive for generalized dot products in JAX and XLA.

#### Iterating over `vector_dot`

Now, suppose you have a 2D input, and you'd like to apply this function to each row. There are several ways you could imagine doing this: three examples are using a Python `for` loop, using `jax.vmap`, or using `jax.lax.map`:

```py
def batched_dot_for_loop(x_batched, y):
  return jnp.array([vector_dot(x, y) for x in x_batched])

def batched_dot_lax_map(x_batched, y):
  return jax.lax.map(lambda x: vector_dot(x, y), x_batched)

batched_dot_vmap = jax.vmap(vector_dot, in_axes=(0, None))
```

Applying these three functions to a batched input yields the same results, to within floating point precision:

```py
x_batched = rng.uniform(size=(4, 50))

print(batched_dot_for_loop(x_batched, y))
# [11.964929  12.485695  13.683528  12.9286175]

print(batched_dot_lax_map(x_batched, y))
# [11.964929  12.485695  13.683528  12.9286175]

print(batched_dot_vmap(x_batched, y))
# [11.964927  12.485697  13.683528  12.9286175]
```

But if we look at the `jaxpr` for each, we can see that the three approaches lead to very different computational characteristics.

The `for` loop solution looks like this:

```py
print(jax.make_jaxpr(batched_dot_for_loop)(x_batched, y))
```

```
{ lambda ; a:f32[4,50] b:f32[50]. let
    c:f32[1,50] = slice[
      limit_indices=(1, 50)
      start_indices=(0, 0)
      strides=(1, 1)
    ] a
    d:f32[50] = squeeze[dimensions=(0,)] c
    e:f32[] = dot_general[dimension_numbers=(([0], [0]), ([], []))] d b
    f:f32[1,50] = slice[
      limit_indices=(2, 50)
      start_indices=(1, 0)
      strides=(1, 1)
    ] a
    g:f32[50] = squeeze[dimensions=(0,)] f
    h:f32[] = dot_general[dimension_numbers=(([0], [0]), ([], []))] g b
    i:f32[1,50] = slice[
      limit_indices=(3, 50)
      start_indices=(2, 0)
      strides=(1, 1)
    ] a
    j:f32[50] = squeeze[dimensions=(0,)] i
    k:f32[] = dot_general[dimension_numbers=(([0], [0]), ([], []))] j b
    l:f32[1,50] = slice[
      limit_indices=(4, 50)
      start_indices=(3, 0)
      strides=(1, 1)
    ] a
    m:f32[50] = squeeze[dimensions=(0,)] l
    n:f32[] = dot_general[dimension_numbers=(([0], [0]), ([], []))] m b
    o:f32[1] = broadcast_in_dim[broadcast_dimensions=() shape=(1,)] e
    p:f32[1] = broadcast_in_dim[broadcast_dimensions=() shape=(1,)] h
    q:f32[1] = broadcast_in_dim[broadcast_dimensions=() shape=(1,)] k
    r:f32[1] = broadcast_in_dim[broadcast_dimensions=() shape=(1,)] n
    s:f32[4] = concatenate[dimension=0] o p q r
  in (s,) }
```

The key feature is that the iterations in the `for` loop are unrolled into a single long program.

The `lax.map` version looks like this:

```py
print(jax.make_jaxpr(batched_dot_lax_map)(x_batched, y))
```

```
{ lambda ; a:f32[4,50] b:f32[50]. let
    c:f32[4] = scan[
      jaxpr={ lambda ; d:f32[50] e:f32[50]. let
          f:f32[] = dot_general[dimension_numbers=(([0], [0]), ([], []))] e d
        in (f,) }
      length=4
      linear=(False, False)
      num_carry=0
      num_consts=1
      reverse=False
      unroll=1
    ] b a
  in (c,) }
```

The key feature is that it is loaded into a `scan` primitive, which is XLA's native static loop operation.

The `vmap` version looks like this:

```py
print(jax.make_jaxpr(batched_dot_vmap)(x_batched, y))
```

```
{ lambda ; a:f32[4,50] b:f32[50]. let
    c:f32[4] = dot_general[dimension_numbers=(([1], [0]), ([], []))] a b
  in (c,) }
```

The key feature here is that the `vmap` transformation is able to recognize that a batched 1D dot product is equivalent to a 2D dot product, so the result is a single extremely efficient native operation.

#### Performance considerations

These three approaches can have very different performance characteristics. The details will depend on the specifics of the original function (here `vector_dot`) but in broad strokes, we can consider three aspects:

##### Compilation Cost

If you JIT-compile your program, you'll find:

- The `for`-loop based solution will have compilation times that grow super-linearly with the number of iterations. This is due to the unrolling seen in the jaxpr above.
- The `lax.map` and `jax.vmap` solutions will have fast compilation time, which under normal circumstances will not grow with the size of the batch dimension.

##### Runtime

In terms of runtime:

- The `for` loop solution can be very fast, because XLA can often fuse operations between the unrolled iterations. This is the flip side of the long compilation times.
- The `lax.map` solution will generally be slow, because it is always executed sequentially with no possibilty of fusing/parallelization between iterations.
- The `jax.vmap` solution will generally be the fastest, especially on accelerators like GPU or TPU, because it can make use of native batching parallelism on the device.

##### Memory Cost

- The `for` loop and `lax.map` solutions generally have good memory performance, because they execute sequentially and don't require storage of large intermediate results.
- The main downside of the `jax.vmap` solution is that it can cause memory to blow up because the entire problem must fit into memory at once. This is not an issue with the simple `vector_dot` function used here, but can be for more complicated functions.

#### Benchmarks

You can see these general principles at play when benchmarking the above functions. The following timings are on a Colab T4 GPU:

```py
y = rng.uniform(size=1000)
x_batched = rng.uniform(size=(200, 1000))
```

```py
%time jax.jit(batched_dot_for_loop).lower(x_batched, y).compile()
# CPU times: user 4.96 s, sys: 55 ms, total: 5.01 s
# Wall time: 7.24 s
%timeit jax.jit(batched_dot_for_loop)(x_batched, y).block_until_ready()
# 1.09 ms ± 149 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```py
%time jax.jit(batched_dot_lax_map).lower(x_batched, y).compile()
# CPU times: user 117 ms, sys: 2.71 ms, total: 120 ms
# Wall time: 172 ms
%timeit jax.jit(batched_dot_lax_map)(x_batched, y).block_until_ready()
# 2.67 ms ± 56.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```py
%time jax.jit(batched_dot_vmap).lower(x_batched, y).compile()
# CPU times: user 51 ms, sys: 941 µs, total: 52 ms
# Wall time: 103 ms
%timeit jax.jit(batched_dot_vmap)(x_batched, y).block_until_ready()
# 719 µs ± 129 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you! This information should be part of JAX's documentation (if it isn't there already).